# How can I get Pysopg2 to work after successful installation on Mac

Tags: postgresql, airflow, psycopg2

I have installed Postgresql on Mac and now created a virtual environment where I have airflow installed. I want to use Postgresql as the backend for airflow and I try to install Pyscopg2 on the virtual environment using `pip install psycopg2-binary` . it installed successfully and I modified the `airflow.cfg` to use Postgresql as the backend.

when I tried initializing the database with airflow db init I got this error

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/abiodunadeoye/KINGS-PLATFORM/Airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpq.5.dylib
  Referenced from: <33951C2B-E899-3F1B-AD87-FC7C9346CFA9> /Users/abiodunadeoye/KINGS-PLATFORM/Airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

I've surfed the internet for solutions but can't seem to get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error message the `dyld` cannot find the `libpq.5.dylib` which is needed to connect `psycopg2` to the Postgres database, check if this library is installed using:

`brew list libpq`

If it isn’t, you can install it by running

`brew install libpq`